# Using Django localsettings.py with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, settings

I am using a combination of `settings.py (saved in git)` and `localsettings.py (not saved in git)` to configure my app and keep sensitive info out of git.

I'm deploying the `Elastic Beanstalk` for the first time and can't figure out how to upload or create the `localsettings.py` in the correct place.

If I scp it it appears as the ec-user and I can't create the file with the right ownership directly in the deployment directory.

The ultimate setup for me would be to have a "master" file that lives just above the `/var/app/current` directory that I can copy into the correct place whenever I deploy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more eloquent way to do this but this is how I did it.

run to get the correct ssh key info

```
eb ssh
```

There will be an INFO line like this showing the key and host

```
INFO: Running ssh -i /Users/joe/.ssh/aws-eb ec2-user@ip-address
```

scp the file to the tmp directory of the host:

```
scp -i /Users/joe/.ssh/aws-eb ./localsettings.py ec2-user@ip-address:/tmp
```

log on the server: `eb ssh`

Move the file to the correct place and change ownership:

```
sudo mv /tmp/localsettings.py /var/app/current/project
sudo chown webapp:webapp /var/app/current/project/localsettings.py
```

**NOTE:** *in my case the file permissions were already correct but you should check those to be sure*

Comment: EDIT: I found out that putting these file manually on the server causes them to go away in certain  cases so I am storing them on S3 and accessing them via `wget` which seems to be working well.